# I am trying to use ManyChat and Make for automatization but it stopped sending fields at all

Tags: make.com, manychats

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvgZr.png) this is empty one but it has to be like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRg50.png). I dont understand where is the problem. I tested everything on the other bot and the result is the same.

Help me with whis trouble.